# Get the last substring in string?

Tags: python, string, substring

```
[Parsed_cropdetect_0 @ 0x7f8ee9c22c60] x1:438 x2:841 y1:0 y2:718 w:400 h:704 x:440 y:8 pts:638638 t:10.643967 crop=400:704:440:8
[Parsed_cropdetect_0 @ 0x7f8ee9c22c60] x1:438 x2:841 y1:0 y2:718 w:400 h:704 x:440 y:8 pts:640640 t:10.677333 crop=400:704:440:8
[Parsed_cropdetect_0 @ 0x7f8ee9c22c60] x1:438 x2:841 y1:0 y2:718 w:400 h:704 x:440 y:8 pts:642642 t:10.710700 crop=400:704:440:8
[Parsed_cropdetect_0 @ 0x7f8ee9c22c60] x1:438 x2:841 y1:0 y2:718 w:400 h:704 x:440 y:8 pts:644644 t:10.744067 crop=400:704:440:8
[Parsed_cropdetect_0 @ 0x7f8ee9c22c60] x1:438 x2:841 y1:0 y2:718 w:400 h:704 x:440 y:8 pts:646646 t:10.777433 crop=400:704:440:8
[Parsed_cropdetect_0 @ 0x7f8ee9c22c60] x1:438 x2:841 y1:0 y2:718 w:400 h:704 x:440 y:8 pts:648648 t:10.810800 crop=400:704:440:8
[Parsed_cropdetect_0 @ 0x7f8ee9c22c60] x1:438 x2:841 y1:0 y2:718 w:400 h:704 x:440 y:8 pts:650650 t:10.844167 crop=400:704:440:8
frame=  326 fps=0.0 q=0.0 Lsize=N/A time=00:00:10.89 bitrate=N/A    
video:31kB audio:1876kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
```

How would you get the last substring "crop=400:704:440:8" string? What I can think of is using rfind("crop=") to get the initial index but I'm not sure what i would do next?

My solution:

```
start =  output.rfind("crop=")
end =  output.find('\n', start, len(output))

print output[start:end]
```

Comment: If you have index and size.You can do like this `a[index:index+size]`

Comment: @AshwaniDausodia The numbers following the final crop will change depending on what I input. So I don't know how big they will be.

Comment: Data seems to be `list` not `string` please clear your question?

Comment: @VishnuUpadhyay It's a string...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the below `re.findall` function.

```
>>> import re
>>> s = """[Parsed_cropdetect_0 @ 0x7f8ee9c22c60] x1:438 x2:841 y1:0 y2:718 w:400 h:704 x:440 y:8 pts:638638 t:10.643967 crop=400:704:440:8
[Parsed_cropdetect_0 @ 0x7f8ee9c22c60] x1:438 x2:841 y1:0 y2:718 w:400 h:704 x:440 y:8 pts:640640 t:10.677333 crop=400:704:440:8
[Parsed_cropdetect_0 @ 0x7f8ee9c22c60] x1:438 x2:841 y1:0 y2:718 w:400 h:704 x:440 y:8 pts:642642 t:10.710700 crop=400:704:440:8
[Parsed_cropdetect_0 @ 0x7f8ee9c22c60] x1:438 x2:841 y1:0 y2:718 w:400 h:704 x:440 y:8 pts:644644 t:10.744067 crop=400:704:440:8
[Parsed_cropdetect_0 @ 0x7f8ee9c22c60] x1:438 x2:841 y1:0 y2:718 w:400 h:704 x:440 y:8 pts:646646 t:10.777433 crop=400:704:440:8
[Parsed_cropdetect_0 @ 0x7f8ee9c22c60] x1:438 x2:841 y1:0 y2:718 w:400 h:704 x:440 y:8 pts:648648 t:10.810800 crop=400:704:440:8
[Parsed_cropdetect_0 @ 0x7f8ee9c22c60] x1:438 x2:841 y1:0 y2:718 w:400 h:704 x:440 y:8 pts:650650 t:10.844167 crop=400:704:440:8
frame=  326 fps=0.0 q=0.0 Lsize=N/A time=00:00:10.89 bitrate=N/A    
video:31kB audio:1876kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown"""
>>> re.findall(r'crop=[\d:]+', s)[-1]
'crop=400:704:440:8'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `str.split` and `str.startswith` with indexing.

```
a = """[Parsed_cropdetect_0 @ 0x7f8ee9c22c60] x1:438 x2:841 y1:0 y2:718 w:400 h:704 x:440 y:8 pts:638638 t:10.643967 crop=400:704:440:8
[Parsed_cropdetect_0 @ 0x7f8ee9c22c60] x1:438 x2:841 y1:0 y2:718 w:400 h:704 x:440 y:8 pts:640640 t:10.677333 crop=400:704:440:8
[Parsed_cropdetect_0 @ 0x7f8ee9c22c60] x1:438 x2:841 y1:0 y2:718 w:400 h:704 x:440 y:8 pts:642642 t:10.710700 crop=400:704:440:8
[Parsed_cropdetect_0 @ 0x7f8ee9c22c60] x1:438 x2:841 y1:0 y2:718 w:400 h:704 x:440 y:8 pts:644644 t:10.744067 crop=400:704:440:8
[Parsed_cropdetect_0 @ 0x7f8ee9c22c60] x1:438 x2:841 y1:0 y2:718 w:400 h:704 x:440 y:8 pts:646646 t:10.777433 crop=400:704:440:8
[Parsed_cropdetect_0 @ 0x7f8ee9c22c60] x1:438 x2:841 y1:0 y2:718 w:400 h:704 x:440 y:8 pts:648648 t:10.810800 crop=400:704:440:8
[Parsed_cropdetect_0 @ 0x7f8ee9c22c60] x1:438 x2:841 y1:0 y2:718 w:400 h:704 x:440 y:8 pts:650650 t:10.844167 crop=400:704:440:8
frame=  326 fps=0.0 q=0.0 Lsize=N/A time=00:00:10.89 bitrate=N/A    
video:31kB audio:1876kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown"""

for line in a.split('\n'):
    if line.split()[-1].startswith('crop'):
        print line.split()[-1] 


>>> 
crop=400:704:440:8
crop=400:704:440:8
crop=400:704:440:8
crop=400:704:440:8
crop=400:704:440:8
crop=400:704:440:8
crop=400:704:440:8
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use awk to print the n:th column:

```
awk '{print $14}' file
```

You can filter out all lines that does not have at least 14 columns with the following syntax:

```
awk 'NF==14 {print $14}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using regex? I would suggest the pattern :

```
((crop=)(\d|:)*(\d))
```

You may use http://regex101.com/ to build your own new one.

Answer (score 0):

If you have each of those lines as a separate string, you can extract the last substring for that line as:

```
# STRING FOR THAT LINE
s = """[Parsed_cropdetect_0 @ 0x7f8ee9c22c60] x1:438 x2:841 y1:0 y2:718 w:400 h:704 x:440 y:8 pts:650650 t:10.844167 crop=400:704:440:8"""

# EXTRACT LAST SUBSTRING
s.split()[-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

if

```
x = "crop=400:704:440:8"
```

then use

```
x[-1]
```

it will return the last character in the string